# JQuery $.ajax, $.get issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a 
**$(".clickButton").click(function()** that loads a page using **$.ajax** and return the result to a DIV. This works perfectly in Chrome, FireFox and Safari, but not IE11.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "go.php?ab=1",
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        $("#res").html(data);       
   }
});
```

As a quick test I tried the following and again it works in Chrome, FireFox and Safari but not IE11.

```
$.get('go.php?ab=1', function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
{ alert(jqXHR); });
```

The date being returned is text and is either **OK** or **ERROR**.
The go.php is running multiple command line scripts and depending what the variables passed depneds on what runs.

All that part is fine and it works really well in the 3 browsers, but not IE11.

When the page first loads in IE it sort of works, it appears to run the go script and return a result. But any subsequent click return instant and the go.php page isn't called. Results are displayed but they appear to be the first processes return results. It's as if the result and process have been cached.

Any ideas how to make this work in IE as it does in the others ?

Comment: `url: "go.php?ab=1",` you have missed to add `"`, may be typo

Comment: Thanks it was a typo here. As I say it works fine in everything bar IE 11.

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Comment: ^^ `console.log($.fn.jquery)` with open console (F12)

Comment: Do you see any information about the request in the IE console? (F12)

Comment: If the issue is related to caching, try adding `cache:false` to your ajax call.

Comment: You might be running any add-on, if means it may interfere. SO, try running IE with -extoff command line option to see the problems occurs.

Comment: @showdev - nothing shows in the console in IE.
I'll try with cache:false and with -extoff

Comment: @Kevin B - jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.0

Comment: Running with -extoff didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's as if the result and process have been cached.

This is possible. If you are sending multiple GET requests to the same URL your browser may be caching the result. If you wanted to verify this you could click the button, clear your cache without reloading the page, and click the button again to see if it works as expected this time.

To prevent caching of GET requests you can add

```
cache: false
```

to your $.ajax options for each request, or you could disable it for all requests by using

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: disabling the cache hasn't helped.

Comment: Can you post your updated code? I was able to recreate your situation, where it worked in Firefox but did not change after the initial click in Internet Explorer 11. However, adding cache: false fixed it for me. Also, before that I was able to verify the cache was the issue by clearing the cache in between clicks.

Comment: Hi. I'm not at my PC at the moment. I've added `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` just inside the click function. One thing I have noticed is one of my go scripts restarts Apache. Once that has happened none of the other buttons work until I reload the page. Again this is only in IE, in the others they all work fine.

Comment: setting `cache: false` and adding html headers to stop caching appears to have resolved this :) Thx

Comment: Can you edit my answer to show the HTML headers you added for future viewers? Or post them as a comment and I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if we been to the same problem, but just earlier I was trying to `get the responce data` from the `go.php` and add it into a `div`.

My code goes like this.

**onClick:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gimmeData(){

                    var url = 'go.php';
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    data:{'something':'1'},
                    success:function(results)
                    {   
                        $('#add_data').html(results);
                    }
                    });
                }
</script>
```

this will give `go.php?something=1` url.

**html:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="gimmeData();" value="clickme!" />
<div id="add_data"></div>
```

**button click**

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var a = $(this).data('first');
    var b = $(this).data('second');
    alert(a + ":" + b);
});
```

**html:**

```
<a id="button" href="#" data-first="something" data-second="something2" onclick="click();">click me</a>
```

using `data()` function. see http://api.jquery.com/data/

or you can do `$(this).attr("data-value")`  to get the value of a `data-attribute`

[JSFiddle sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/zScVg/1/)

Comment: As a basic test this has worked. I'd like to try some further tests.
currently my buttons have a value set as `data-value="go.php?ab=1"`, I then use `$(this).attr("data-value")` to get the correct url. I've changed this so `data-value="{'ab':'1'}"` and added `$(this).attr("data-value")` to `data:`  But that doesn't work. Any way I can pass these vales ?

Comment: you can do is make 2 data-attributes. one for the other value and one for the other and store it in their respective variables and use them.lemme update my answer.